# Format of the multipart boundary in SOAP+MTOM WCF payloads

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, mime, mtom

If you use a client with a custom binding to communicate with a SOAP+MTOM based WCF service, .NET crafts a multipart boundary in the following format:

```
boundary="uuid:f45e6739-e796-41c7-bc96-6dd977a185f6+id=2";
```

My question is, why is it formatted this way? According to the [RFC1341](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html), the boundary does not *need* to have this format. So I am wondering, if anyone has any insights into this, why does .NET add the `uuid:` prefix and why does it add the `+id=#` suffix? Why doesn't .NET drop the prefix and the suffix in favor of just the GUID portion? What is a use case in which it is a benefit to have the prefix and the suffix added to the boundary?